# Is 1 phase commit (ChainedTransactionManager) really necessary in this scenario vs no transaction management?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions, transactionmanager

I have a Spring Boot application with a `@JmsListener` that receives a message from a queue, stores it in database and sends it to another queue.

I wanted to have a minimal transactional guarantee so 1-phase-commit works for me. After a lot of reading I found I could use the [ChainedTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html) to coordinate the DataSource and JMS resources:

```
@Configuration
public class TransactionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ChainedTransactionManager transactionManager(JpaTransactionManager jpaTm, JmsTransactionManager jmsTm) {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(jmsTm, jpaTm);
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
    }

}
```

Queue listener:

```
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
    @JmsListener(...)
    public void process(@Payload String message) {
        //Write to db
        //Send to output queue
    }
```

```
START MESSAGING TX
START DB TX
READ MESSAGE
WRITE DB
SEND MESSAGE
COMMIT DB TX
COMMIT MESSAGING TX
```

- If the db commit fails the message will be reprocesed again
- If the db commit succeeds but the messaging commit fails the message will be reprocessed. This it not a problem since I can guarantee the idempotency of the db write operation

Now my doubt is, let's suppose I hadn't configured the `ChainedTransactionManager` and the listener were like this (no `@Transactional`):

```
    @JmsListener(...)
    public void process(@Payload String message) {
        //Write to db
        //Send to output queue
    }
```

Doesn't this behave the same as the other example despite not coordinating the commits? (I've verified that on SQL exceptions the message is redelivered)

```
    RECEIVE MESSAGE
    WRITE DB + COMMIT
    SEND MESSAGE + COMMIT
```

- If the DB commit failed the message would be reprocessed
- If it succeeded and the send message operation failed it would be reprocessed again.

So is the `ChainedTransactionManager` really necessary in this case?

**UPDATE**: Debugging the Spring Boot autoconfiguration (`JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration`)...

```
@Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
```

... the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` is configuring the factory with `factory.setSessionTransacted(true);` because there is no `JtaTransactionManager` defined:

```
        if (this.transactionManager != null) {
            factory.setTransactionManager(this.transactionManager);
        }
        else {
            factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        }
```

With setSessionTransacted(true), according to the [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.25.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jms-tx-participation) I would get the message rollback and redelivery behaviour I need on DB (or any) exceptions:

> Local resource transactions can simply be activated through the
>   sessionTransacted flag on the listener container definition. Each
>   message listener invocation will then operate within an active JMS
>   transaction, with message reception rolled back in case of listener
>   execution failure. Sending a response message (via
>   SessionAwareMessageListener) will be part of the same local
>   transaction, but any other resource operations (such as database
>   access) will operate independently. This usually requires duplicate
>   message detection in the listener implementation, covering the case
>   where database processing has committed but message processing failed
>   to commit.

That explains I'm getting the behaviour I expect without needing to configure the `ChainedTransactionManager`.

After all this, could you tell me if it makes sense (it adds some guarantee I'm missing) to use the `ChainedTransactionManager` in this case?